# Get the relevant features from the pipeline and build a DecisionTree

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, decision-tree

I have a pipeline that trains a decision tree. I would like to output the features that were used after the successful training and then I would like to display my decision tree. However, the following error occurs: `AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'n_features_'`

- How can I display the relevant features that were used during the training?
- How can I create the decision tree?

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=30, stratify=y)


feature_selection=SelectFromModel(LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000000))

#scaler = 
classifier=DecisionTreeClassifier()

steps = [('scaler', MinMaxScaler()), ('feature_selection', feature_selection), ('dec_tree', DecisionTreeClassifier())]


pipeline = Pipeline(steps) 

# parameters
parameteres = {'dec_tree__max_depth':[list(range(1,X.shape[1]+1,1))],
                      'dec_tree__criterion':['gini', 'entropy'],
                      'dec_tree__max_depth':[2,4,6,8,10,12]}

grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameteres, cv=5)

grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("score = %3.2f" %(grid.score(X_test,y_test)))
print('Training set score: ' + str(grid.score(X_train,y_train)))
print('Test set score: ' + str(grid.score(X_test,y_test)))
print(grid.best_params_)

y_pred = grid.predict(X_test)
```

As you can see I need the column names or the columns taken during the training at `feature_selection`

```py
# I need the feature_selection the features
# get decision tree
dot_data = StringIO()
# the error occurs here
export_graphviz(grid, out_file=dot_data,  
                filled=True, rounded=True,
                special_characters=True,feature_names = <GET_COLUMNS>,class_names=['0','1']) # I need the column names from feature_selection here
```

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your post to include the full error trace (and remove any code that may come *after* the error).

Comment: @desertnaut please see my edit. and there is no unnecessary code.

Comment: Of course there is (well, was...). Please do not clutter your posts with unnecessary & irrelevant stuff (not even as comments).

Comment: You didn't like the last comment in a position where it can actually be read (now it is just invisible), or you are just editing for editing's sake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran gridsearchcv over a pipeline, so to apply your visualization, you need to pull out the classifier from `best_estimator_` , like:

```
export_graphviz(grid.best_estimator_.named_steps['dec_tree'])
```

An example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier,export_graphviz
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

X,y = make_classification()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=30, stratify=y)

feature_selection=SelectFromModel(LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000000))

classifier=DecisionTreeClassifier()

steps = [('scaler', MinMaxScaler()), ('feature_selection', feature_selection), ('dec_tree', DecisionTreeClassifier())]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps) 

parameteres = {'dec_tree__max_depth':[list(range(1,X.shape[1]+1,1))],
                      'dec_tree__criterion':['gini', 'entropy'],
                      'dec_tree__max_depth':[2,4,6,8,10,12]}

grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameteres, cv=5)

grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(grid.best_params_)
{'dec_tree__criterion': 'gini', 'dec_tree__max_depth': 2}
```

Now we can check the best estimator corresponds to the best param:

```
grid.best_estimator_.named_steps['dec_tree'].get_params()

{'ccp_alpha': 0.0,
 'class_weight': None,
 'criterion': 'gini',
 'max_depth': 2,
 'max_features': None,
 'max_leaf_nodes': None,
 'min_impurity_decrease': 0.0,
 'min_samples_leaf': 1,
 'min_samples_split': 2,
 'min_weight_fraction_leaf': 0.0,
 'random_state': None,
 'splitter': 'best'}
```

Run your function:

```
export_graphviz(grid.best_estimator_.named_steps['dec_tree'])
```

In a similar manner to get the features selected:

```
grid.best_estimator_.named_steps['feature_selection'].get_feature_names_out()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it. Is there also an option to get the column names? Like `feature_names = <GET_COLUMNS>` so I need from the pipeline the columns. I looke for the best features/columns with `feature_selection=SelectFromModel(LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000000))`

Comment: The best features for training should be found and I would like to know what the best features would be. So is there any way to get a list of the column names used for training?

Comment: see edited answer @Test.. next time avoid asking multiple questions in a post

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it. And perfect answer!! You are a real Genius :)